# Execution failed for task':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, manifest-merging

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

how to fix this error?

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `build.gradle` file:

Change

`com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1` to

`com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<application

        tools:replace="icon, label"> <-- Add this line in application tag
```

Comment: mer30 ahmad jan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using different versions of support library. Try using same version for all the android support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

**Try latest version libraries (25.3.1)**

```
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

**Change in app.gradle**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```